# Listening if cookie has changed

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I was wondering if there was a "correct" way to listen for cookie changes on Angular? It would be awesome if I could listen and change values in my models depending on their new values.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried a `$watch` on `$cookieStore.get(...)`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
'use strict';

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $log, $cookies, $timeout) {

    $scope.$watch(function() { return $cookies.test; }, function(newValue) {
        $log.log('Cookie string: ' + $cookies.test)
    });

    $cookies.test = 'first value';

    $timeout(function () {
        $cookies.test = 'second value';
    }, 1000);

});
```

Comment: This method won't work if the cookie is changed from another browser instance.

Comment: This is working only if the cookie value changed on an event manually. It doesn't recognizing the cookie change if it expires. Is there any other possible solution? If it is there, please let me know.